# Enumerate within align environment

Tags: itemize, alignment

I'm trying to reformat a document and came across a long list. Here are some of the items:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \) 
    \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=y x^{y-1} \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x
    \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \)
\end{enumerate}
```

Unfortunately it is messy:

[image: old code]

**I want to align the 2 "natural" columns in the itemize environment.** The following code more or less does what I want:

```
\newcounter{myrownumbers}
\newcommand\myrownumber{\stepcounter{myrownumbers}\makebox[13.5pt][s]{\text{(\alph{myrownumbers})}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
\begin{flalign*}
       &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & &  \pdv{f}{y}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \\
       &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=y x^{y-1} & &  \pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x & \\
       &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y} \right) & &  \pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) &
\end{flalign*}
```

[image: hacked code]

Even ignoring the ugly code, this is not a satisfying solution, however. Because I really want to imitate `itemize`, I added the `hbox` so the alignment does not depend on the width of the label, but this results in a lot of `overfull hbox` warnings.

I also tried solutions using `tabular` and `array`, but could get the labeling to look like `itemize`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}
    Old code:
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \) 
        \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=y x^{y-1} \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x \)
        \item \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \quad  \pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \)
    \end{enumerate}
    \newcounter{myrownumbers}
    \newcommand\myrownumber{\stepcounter{myrownumbers}\makebox[13.5pt][s]{\text{(\alph{myrownumbers})}}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
    I want something like this:
    \begin{flalign*}
           &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & &  \pdv{f}{y}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \\
           &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=y x^{y-1} & &  \pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x & \\
           &\myrownumber \pdv{f}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) & &  \pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) &
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace [s] with [r], 13.5pt with \labelwidth and \tabcolsep with \labelsep and you are there.  BTW, inside \makebox you revert to text mode automatically (see also \mathmakebox from mathtools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code based on `enumerate`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{derivative}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),before={\everymath={\displaystyle}}]
  \item \makebox[0.35\linewidth][l]{\(\pdv{f}{x} = -\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\)}
    \(\pdv{f}{y} = \frac{x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\)
  \item \makebox[0.35\linewidth][l]{\(\pdv{f}{x} = y x^{y-1}\)}
    \(\pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x\)
  \item \makebox[0.35\linewidth][l]{\(\pdv{f}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right)\)}
    \(\pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right)\)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `before={\everymath={\displaystyle}}` alone!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the tasks package :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{derivative}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=(\alph*),label-width=1.4em}% if you want the sames labels as enumerate 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=-\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\) \task[] \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{y}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \) 
        \task \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=y x^{y-1} \) \task[] \( \displaystyle \pdv{f}{y}=x^{y} \ln x \)
        \task \(\displaystyle \pdv{f}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \) \task[] \(\displaystyle   \pdv{f}{y}=-\frac{(x+a)}{2 y \sqrt{y}} \cot \left(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \)
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer does indeed do more or less what I want. Thanks as well for learning me about the `task` package! I went with the other answer because it uses `enumerate` which immediately fits the other styling in my document.